# Are there any ways to remove duplicates in a specific row while maintaining other rows?

Tags: duplicates, powerquery, columnsorting

I'm trying to remove duplicates in a specific column(promotion-ids.1 column) while others remain.

Is there any ways to solve it?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want? It nulls out the contents if the row above it has the same contents in that particular column?  (Sort of the inverse of fill...down...)

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
shiftedList = {null} & List.RemoveLastN(Table.Column(Source,"promotion-ids.1"),1),
custom1 = Table.ToColumns(Source) & {shiftedList},
custom2 = Table.FromColumns(custom1,Table.ColumnNames(Source) & {"Prev"}),
x=Table.ReplaceValue(custom2,  each [#"promotion-ids.1"], each if [Prev]=[#"promotion-ids.1"] then null else[#"promotion-ids.1"] ,Replacer.ReplaceValue,{"promotion-ids.1"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(x,{"Prev"})
in #"Removed Columns"
```

[image]

thats a terrible way to store the data, but might be what you are looking for

Comment: What I mean was just removing duplicates on "promotions-ids.1 column", but the remaining columns row are not erased at all.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what a column row is.  Maybe provide a before/after sample data view

Comment: For example, duplicates on "promotions-ids.1" columns are erased. But none of the rest columns are not erased at all. Just means as total number of rows remains.

Comment: try revised code

Comment: What is a revised code? Could you tell me more about it? I'm just a beginner.

Comment: a revised code means look above I put in a new answer

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tried it but there is an error when I pasted it into advanced editor...

Comment: Sorry, can't help you. I just checked it. Works perfectly using the sample data and column title of image on left